# Linear Algebra - minimal polynomial, polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $(x−1)(x+1)$.  Let $f(x)=4x^{2008} − 8x^{597} + 10x + 6$

1. show $f(A) = \alpha I + \beta A$
2. $\alpha=?\ \beta=?$

So I worked on a bit, and I got this far

$A  =  x^2 - 1$

$A^2 =  x^4 - 2x^2 + 1$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's $q$? What does "$A=x^2-1$" even mean?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear: is $\;A\;$ a matrix (because of the mininal polynomial)? Then what does $\;A=x^2-1\;$  mean?? Something else?

Comment: This has the exactly same ambiguity/confusion as your [prior deleted](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1260045/242) version of the question. It's not nice to delete a question where you have received an answer. Instead you should have clarified the original question.

Comment: Hello Bill: I has been working on this question for 2 days and putting in many hours. I didn't get it myself thus asking people for guidance.  Regarding the ambiguity/confusion you mentioned the question was given to me as I posted and you said it yourself - the same.  Regarding the deleted post, I am new here, account 2 days old; I am so sorry for what I did... all because I'm afraid that my question will be buried under tons of latest questions...but no excuse. So, I am sorry and Bill please forgive me.  Warmest regards.

Comment: @ABC You can ask about the *meaning* of a question: terms, intention, tools to solve ,etc., but *if you ask a question* the very least one should try is to **understand** the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A^2-I=0$, you have $\,f(A)=(f\bmod x^2-1)(A)$.

Now, since $x^2\equiv 1\mod x^2-1$, we have: \begin{align*}f(x)\bmod x^2-1&=4(x^{2008}\bmod x^2-1)-8(x^{597}\bmod x^2-1)+10x+6\\
&=4-8x+10x+6=2x+10,\end{align*}
whence $\,\alpha=10,\enspace \beta=2$.

Comment: See my comment on the question.